# Web api cross two classes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have two classes

```
public class C1 : ApiController { ... 
  public List<C1> GetAll() { ....} // GetAll(string search = null)
}

public class C2 : ApiController { ... 
  public List<C2> GetAll() { ....} // GetAll(string search = null).
}
```

Then I need to add a search function to each class. So I added a search parameter to each `GetAll()` as `GetAll(string search = null)`. The methods will return all the list if `search` is null; otherwise, it will return the filtered result list.

Now I will need to add a search function that searches in the database tables of `C1` and `C2` and returns two lists of `C1` and `C2` (`SearchC1AndC2ViewModel`). Where should I implement the function? Or should I create a new class solely for this function?

```
public class SearchC1AndC2ViewModel { 
  public List<C1> C1s; 
  public List<C2> C2s; 
}
```

Web API to be implemented

```
public SearchC1AndC2ViewModel Search(string search)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I assume you've misused the type parameter in search and GetAll methods, as now it appears the same as your controller.

Looks like you're looking for a mechanism for sharing a common solution.
There are multiple ways to achieve what you're trying to do.

**Option 1: Base Controller Class**

Define a base class for those two controllers, and implement a generic search method in there. It's not ideal to have data access logic right in the controller, so you'll probably move the logic somewhere else and just call from here. Here is what the code would look like in that case:

```
public abstract class CustomControllerBase<T> : ApiController
{
    public List<T> GetAll(string filter = null)
    {
        // Common code goes here.
        // At some point you may need some customization based on the actual implementation
        return this.RetrieveRecords(filter);
    }

    protected abstract List<T> RetrieveRecords(string filter);
}

public class Controller1 : CustomControllerBase <C1>
{
    protected override List<C1> RetrieveRecords (string filter) {
        // Custom logic goes here
    }
}

public class Controller2 : CustomControllerBase <C2>
{
    protected override List<C2> RetrieveRecords (string filter) {
        // Custom logic goes here
    }
}
```

**Option 2: Delegation to data layer**

The second option is to have a dedicated class for data access operations, and make it generic, so it can be reused for multiple types. If the only difference between those two entities you're trying to retrieve from the database (or some other data store) is the type of the entities and the source (table name), you can make those parameters of the data class constructor.

```
public class DataAccessHandler<T>
{
    private Func<QueryResultItem, T> queryResultProcessingLogic;

    public DataAccessHandler(Func<QueryResultItem, T> queryResultProcessingLogic)
    {
        // Validation goes here
        this.queryResultProcessingLogic = queryResultProcessingLogic;
    }

    public List<T> Retrieve(string filter = null)
    {
        QueryResult queryResult = // Retrieve query results given query. this is your custom implementation. QueryResult type is an abstraction, you'll have to replace it with the actual type you use. I'm sharing just the concept here.
        return queryResult.Select(item=>queryResultProcessingLogic(item)).ToList();
    }
}

public class Controller1 : ApiController
{
    private readonly DataAccessHandler<C1> dataHandler;

    public Controller1 ( DataAccessHandler<C1> dataHandler)
    {
        // Validate arguments here

        this.dataHandler = dataHandler;
    }

    public List<C1> GetAll(string filter)
    {
        return this.dataHandler.GetAll(filter);
    }
}
```

The best approach would be to combine both options :)

Hope this helps.

Comment: `CustomControllerBase` has to be abstract in order to have an abstract method

Comment: Good catch, updating. Thanks Marco.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is with creating a class solely for that function's return type then you can have it return a `Tuple<List<C1>, List<C2>>`.

---

Now if you're looking to reuse the `GetAll` methods from the other controllers into a new controller, then **welcome to class composition**! You can't make a controller that inherits both from the `C1` controller and `C2` controller, because a class cannot inherit from more than one class. Instead you have to make an empty interface and extend it with the `GetAll` methods, but as you'll inherit from both interfaces the methods will collide as a call to `GetAll` would become ambiguous, so you will have to also change the method name. But `C1` and `C2` are actually classes that inherit from `ApiController`, and an interface cannot inherit from a class, so you would have to make the interfaces and make `C1` and `C2` inherit both from them and `ApiController`. I don't know who invented this, but it is actually the "proper" way to do it, and **it's a mess**. Here we go:

```
// First define the interfaces
public interface IC1 { }
public interface IC2 { }

// Then extend the with the GetAll methods
public static class ICExtensions
{
  public static List<C1> GetAllC1(this IC1, string search = null) { ... } 
  public static List<C2> GetAllC2(this IC2, string search = null) { ... }
}

// These are now your controllers
public class C1Controller : ApiController, IC1 { ... }
public class C2Controller : ApiController, IC2 { ... }

// And here is the new controller that has the two GetAll methods
public class C1AndC2Controller : ApiController, IC1, IC2 { ... }
```

Now you can freely implement the `GetAll` method in `C1AndC2Controller`, which can return a new class, `Tuple`, whatever you want it to.